# Why does something "strain credulity"?

Tags: phrases, expressions, vocabulary

Credulity, as I have understood it, approximately means "an unreasonable readiness to believe in things".

If something "strains credulity", it apparently means that it is difficult to believe.

However, since credulity already connotes a belief that is unreasonable, why should something difficult to believe "strain" credulity?

If, however, "credulity" meant "the capability of believing in things", I could see how "straining credulity" would make sense, since we would be stretching this capability.

Comment: "since credulity already connotes a belief that is unreasonable" - I think you may have this slightly backwards. Credulity is a capacity to believe something, and as dictionaries note, particularly it is used to suggest belief in something without a lot of evidence. However, the word still sounds like an affirmative (i.e. it's about the capacity to believe), where in contrast, something that is "not credible" is not to be believed. Similary, incredulity is basically the opposite of credulity. Incredible is also a related word, and there are probably many others.

Comment: If the context of use were provided, readers of your question would be much more apt to give you an answer.

Comment: So basically I think your bottom paragraph probably has already answered your own question.

Comment: "Readiness or willingness to believe **especially on slight or uncertain evidence**" [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/credulity). We may be willing to go  along with a premise based on little evidence (say in a good novel); however, if the premise is too farfetched or the evidence too poor, we can see how "straining credulity" fits.

Answer (score 3):

[The Web Site of Professor Paul Brians](https://brians.wsu.edu/2016/05/31/credible/)

> Although you will commonly see it said of some far-fetched story
> either that “it strains credulity” or that “it strains credibility,”
> the latter is more traditional. Something that strains credulity would
> be beyond the powers of even a very gullible person to believe. This
> form of the saying isn’t very effective because a credulous person
> isn’t straining to believe things anyway. Such a person believes
> easily without thinking. It makes more sense to say that something too
> weird or wild to be credible “strains credibility.”

Answer (score 0):

A couple of definitions are helpful.

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/credulity)
> *credulity*
> willingness to believe that something is real or true, especially when this is unlikely

the believing therefore depends on a willingness to believe, despite unlikeliness. This implies that credulity is given willingly by the believer, not elicited by the unlikeliness.

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/strain)
> *strain*
> a force or influence that stretches, pulls, or puts pressure on something;
> to cause too much of something to be used;
> to cause anxiety or problems.

With these definitions and usage in mind, we may understand that to strain credulity is to force it, to pull it in a way makes difficulties, in a way that is not naturally easy. Strained credulity is not given, it is forced.

A similar construct is used by Shakespeare in the well-known:
"*The quality of mercy is not strained*"

> [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Merchant-of-Venice-Shakespeare-play-What-does-the-quality-of-mercy-is-not-strained-mean)
> "*The quality of mercy is not strained*"
> A line from the play The Merchant of Venice, by William Shakespeare.
> Strained means “constrained,” or “forced”;
> the speaker is telling Shylock that mercy must be freely given, and is inviting him to show mercy to the title character.

Similarly, credulity (being a state of mind) can only be given from the mind, it cannot be forced by external circumstance, whether likely or not.

Answer (score 0):

The expression 'strains credulity' is found as far back as 1832:

[Records and Briefs of the United States Supreme Court 1832 p 118 {via Google}](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Records_and_Briefs_of_the_United_States/Z7qiJ3Xtz6AC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22strains+credulity%22&pg=RA7-PA118&printsec=frontcover):

> - *And it strains credulity to assume that this defendant , who under the evidence wilfully violated the statute , had to engage in any such
>   guesswork with respect to the law governing his conduct*

This, coupled with an earlier definition for 'credulity' [[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/credulity)]:

> **credulity** (countable and uncountable, plural credulities)
>
> (now nonstandard) Faith, credence; acceptance or maintenance of a
> belief

shows that the straining / testing of credulity (in this older sense, part of one believes) is unremarkable.